# Any other way to avoid if else condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following stored procedure. I have variable `@PercentCleared` .

`IF @PercentCleared <= 70` then I have to subtract `PercentCleared-10` else use as it is. Can you please advise me the right way to do?

```
    DECLARE @PercentCleared INT
    DECLARE @TenPercent int

    SET @TenPercent = 10

    IF(@PercentCleared <=70)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @I, dbo.tblV.VegTypeCode, dbo.tblV.VegTypeName 
        FROM 
            dbo.tblVegetationType 
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblVegFormationLink ON dbo.tblV.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegFormationLink.VegTypeID
        WHERE   
            dbo.tblVegetationType.PercentageCleared >=(@PercentCleared - @TenPercent)
        WHERE 
            a.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID 
            AND dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID <> (SELECT VegTypeID 
                                                    FROM @EcosystemCredits eco 
                                                    WHERE eco.theID = @I) 
    END
    ELSE IF
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @I, dbo.tblV.VegTypeCode, dbo.tblV.VegTypeName
        FROM 
            dbo.tblVegetationType 
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblVegFormationLink ON dbo.tblV.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegFormationLink.VegTypeID
        WHERE   
            dbo.tblVegetationType.PercentageCleared >=@PercentCleared
        WHERE 
            a.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID 
            AND dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID <> (SELECT VegTypeID 
                                                    FROM @EcosystemCredits eco WHERE eco.theID = @I) 

    End
```

Comment: That is very hard to read.  Can you reformat for greater clarity?  (I'm sorry, but I don't have the energy to do it for you.)  The name `@TenPercent` isn't a very good choice; either just write the 10 or give it a more meaningful name.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, i am reformatting now

Comment: Is the 'else if' meant to be just 'else'?  There's no condition for the 'if' part of the 'else if'.  That's trivia, though.  The rest is more easily read now.  Can't you use something like `CASE @PercentCleared WHEN >= 70 THEN @PercentCleared - @TenPercent ELSE @PercentCleared END` in place of the `@PercentCleared` condition in one of the SELECT statements, so you then don't need the other or the outer IF/ELSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this by using a CASE statement in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT @I,  dbo.tblV.VegTypeCode,  dbo.tblV.VegTypeName FROM dbo.tblVegetationType 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblVegFormationLink
  ON dbo.tblV.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegFormationLink.VegTypeID
WHERE dbo.tblVegetationType.PercentageCleared 
      >= @PercentCleared 
         - CASE WHEN (@PercentCleared <=70) THEN @TenPercent ELSE 0 END -- change here
WHERE a.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID 
AND dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID 
    <> (SELECT VegTypeID FROM @EcosystemCredits eco WHERE eco.theID = @I)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the logic in the `where` clause.

```
SELECT @I,  dbo.tblV.VegTypeCode, vt.VegTypeName
FROM dbo.tblVegetationType vt INNER JOIN
     dbo.tblVegFormationLink vfl
     ON vt.VegTypeID = vlt.VegTypeID
WHERE (vt.PercentageCleared >= @PercentCleared - (CASE WHEN @PercentCleared <= 70 THEN @TenPercent ELSE 0 END)) AND
      (vt.VegTypeID <> (SELECT VegTypeID FROM @EcosystemCredits eco WHERE eco.theID = @I) );
```

I simplified the query by using table aliases.  Also, you had two `where` clauses and the second was redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without a **CASE** or **IF** statement by re-writing your SQL like this...

```
WHERE   
    (@PercentCleared <=70 AND dbo.tblVegetationType.PercentageCleared >=(@PercentCleared - @TenPercent))
OR
    (@PercentCleared > 70 AND dbo.tblVegetationType.PercentageCleared >= @PercentCleared)
```

Hope it helps not only in this situation but many similar situtations.